# How to use SASS or LESS mixins within a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I implemented *twitter-bootstrap 3* in my application with *bootstrap-sass* (https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) **but I was not able to use a theme** from http://bootswatch.com/ with this method (because it doesn't provide the css files).

Then, I finally managed to install the theme from bootswatch **by removing the gem**, and using only the **CSS files downloaded directly** from twitter-bootstrap website. (I followed this tutorial : http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application/ ). It worked great so far, but I came across this article http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html and decided to improve my code by using the bootstrap *mixins*.

I found this approach very interesting and I would like to use it in my project :

```
article {
  .makeRow();

  section.main {
    .makeColumn(10);
  }

  aside {
    .makeColumn(2);
  }
}
```

Considering what I said about using a theme without a gem, how could I use *LESS* or *SASS mixins* ?

**EDIT**

Is there no other way than manually compile LESS code ? (as Bass Jobsen suggested) because it's really not convenient..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to compile your less code. Use the less files of your Twitter's Bootstrap 3 download.

Add your less code shown above to bootstraps.less, use a less compiler (some examples http://lesscss.org/#usage or https://github.com/twitter/recess) to compile this to bootstrap.css and copy this file to your `vendor/assets/` directory.

Also see: [How can I create multiple rows using semantic markup in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553469/how-can-i-create-multiple-rows-using-semantic-markup-in-bootstrap-3/20556902) and notice `makeRow` and `makeColumn` in your example code are not valid mixins of the current Bootstrap release.

**update**
Your question was SASS or LESS, so i answerd LESS. I expect you could do the same with SASS. From reading this: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass#sass it think you should import `bootstrap-and-overrides.css.scss`  into `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-custom.scss`

Comment: Still, it is really not a convenient method :( I tried to import SASS files from thomas-mcdonalod repository and use sass mixins into my bootstrap-and-overrides.css.scss file but it doesn't work either :(

Comment: i do work with LESS mostly. Does it work without your `bootstrap-and-overrides.css.scss`?

Comment: nevermind. I was a bit lost here. I now use the gem bootstrap-sass and override bootstrap default theme by importing the new css in my application.css :-) (I can use SASS mixins this way) thank you for you time