# How can you properly layout a bootstrap3 css grid using a mustache template?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, mustache

I am trying to use a simple mustache template with a list of items and display them in rows of 3 columns.  The problem I am facing is how to get the "row" logic into the template (every 3 columns, start a new row).

Here is my template:

```
<div class="row">
    {{#listings}}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Item {{number}}
        </div>
    {{/listings}}
</div>
```

Bootstrap doesn't seem to like the fact that I shove way too many columns into the row.  I did exactly this with foundation by zurb and it worked without a hitch.

Can anyone out there point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all you col-md-4's in the same row. 3x col-md-4 makes 100% and the next one jump to next row. This could give you troubles when your col-md-4's differs in height, see also: [How can I create multiple rows using semantic markup in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553469/how-can-i-create-multiple-rows-using-semantic-markup-in-bootstrap-3/2055690) and [Change overflow mode in small devices on Twitter Bootstrap 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754008/change-overflow-mode-in-small-devices-on-twitter-bootstrap-3-0/19777087)

Comment: Thanks Bass, it does indeed seem to be working fine now, perhaps I had uneven content at first.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't making an obvious mistake.  Coincidentally, thanks also for your typeahead fork as I am using that too :)